# Use Dukt Videos with HTTPS

Tags: plugins, https, plugin-duktvideos

This is a specific question about the Dukt videos plugin. I have a site that's all HTTPS and I can't seem to find a way to switch all the embeds to also use HTTPS?  Is there an option anyone else knows of?

Comment: Did you contact Dukt already? support@dukt.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've run into this as well.  I don't know if there is a better fix, but for our case, we ended up using the video url parameter and the replace filter to get around it:

```
{% if entry.video|length %}

<iframe src="{{ entry.video.url|replace("http://youtu.be/", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/")|raw }}?wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="true" enablejsapi="1"></iframe>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: That works, and probably a little less hacks than what we did.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry about that guys, this issue has been fixed in Videos 1.0.20:

https://dukt.net/craft/videos/updates#v1.0.20

Answer (score 1):

So not a great solution but I wanted to share what we ended up doing

We edited the plugin directly by editing the getEmbedFormat() function in

craft/plugins/videos/vendor/dukt/videos/src/Dukt/Videos/Vimeo/Video.php

And just change the http to http so it's just.

```
return "https://player.vimeo.com/video/%s";
```

Also going to reach out to dukt to see if he'd change the default in the main plugin since https will work any site (with or without ssl)